# Problems with if statement in a password generator

Tags: python

I am having problem with my if statement in my code:

```
import random

def passcheck():
    pass_verify = input("Enter the password to login: ")

    while pass_verify != password:
        pass_verify = input("Try again: ")

    print("Correct")
    option = input("Do you want to read or write in the document[r/w]: ")


    if option == 'w':
        file = open("Doc.txt","w+")
        text = input("What do you wanna write: ")
        file.write(text + '\n')
        file.close()

    elif option == 'r':
        file = open("Doc.txt","r")
        file.read()
        file.close

    else:
        print("Invalid input")

username = input("Enter a username: ")

#password generator
lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
special = '!"£$%^&*.,@#/?'

p1 = random.sample(lower,1)
p2 = random.sample(lower,1)
p3 = random.sample(lower,1)
p4 = random.sample(lower,1)
p5 = random.sample(upper,1)
p6 = random.sample(upper,1)
p7 = random.sample(upper,1)
p8 = random.sample(upper,1)
p9 = random.sample(special,1)
p0 = random.sample(special,1)


password1 = "".join(p1+p5+p2+p6+p9+p3+p7+p0+p4+p8)
choice = input("Do you want to enter your own password or you wanna continue woth the suggested 
password: "+password1+" [own/con]")

if choice == 'own':
    print("It must be more than 8 characters and should have atleast a lower case, upper case and a 
    special character")
    password2 = input("Enter your password: ")
    if len(password2) < 8:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    elif password2.find(lower) == -1:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    elif password2.find(upper) == -1:
       print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    elif password2.find(special) == -1:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    else:
        password = password2 
        passcheck()

elif choice == 'con':
    password = password1
    passcheck()

else:
    print("Error")
```

the part which says

```
if choice == 'own':
    print("It must be more than 8 characters and should have atleast a lower case, upper case and a 
    special character")
    password2 = input("Enter your password: ")
    if len(password2) < 8:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    elif password2.find(lower) == -1:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    elif password2.find(upper) == -1:
       print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    elif password2.find(special) == -1:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments")
    else:
        password = password2 
        passcheck()
```

is like a checker and it checks if the password they made has at least 8, lowercase, uppercase and special character and if I input 'TesT@TesT' as my password it should work but the ouput it:

```
Enter a username: Vedant
Do you want to enter your own password or you wanna continue woth the suggested password: zKeZ"nA%iC 
[own/con]own
It must be more than 8 characters and should have atleast a lower case, upper case and a special 
character
Enter your password: TesT@TesT
Doesnt meeet the requirments
```

If i input 'TesT@TesT' it should work as there is more than 8 characters(9),lowercase(es..es),uppercase(T..T.T..T) and a special character(@)

Comment: If you change your "Doesnt meeet the requirments" message to a different one for each problem ("Too short", "Does not contain a lowercase letter" etc.) it will be easier both for you to debug the code and for the user to come up with a valid password…

Comment: ok thx i will defienety improve my code accordingly

Comment: And another hint: reread the description of `str.find`.

Comment: i did and i think the main problem is there, I think it is trying to find the whole string in the password but im not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the `password2.find`, try using `any`:

```
if choice == 'own':
    print("It must be more than 8 characters and should have atleast a lower case, upper case and aspecial character")
    password2 = input("Enter your password: ")
    if len(password2) < 8:
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments (len)")
    elif not any(char in password2 for char in lower):
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments (lower)")
    elif not any(char in password2 for char in upper):
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments (upper)")
    elif not any(char in password2 for char in special):
        print("Doesnt meeet the requirments (special)")
    else:
        password = password2
        passcheck()
```

---

To simplify the creation of a random password you can use:

```
import string, random
lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
special = '!"£$%^&*.,@#/?'

def rand_pass():
    p = []
    [p.append(random.choice(lower)) for x in range(4)]
    [p.append(random.choice(upper)) for x in range(4)]
    [p.append(random.choice(special)) for x in range(2)]
    random.shuffle(p)
    return "".join(p)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code the mistake is in "choice" part, the syntax and the choice accepting statement was not functioning correctly.
after password1 statement, please reduce the length of the choice.

In my opinion like this:

```
 choice = str(input("Do you want Your own password:");
```

then give the choice in your "if" condition as,

```
 if choice == 'yes'
```

and the else statement as,

```
 else choice == 'no'
```

Comment: The input of the choice variable works ok. If you add `print(f'You chose {choice=}')` (Python 3.8 syntax) after the assignment, you'd get `You chose choice='own'`.

While I agree that prompting for 'yes/no' own a more intuitive interface than own/con, it wouldn't address the problem here (which lies in the way `str.find()` is being used)